# Lagging when change date and time on iPhone

Tags: ios, reactjs, datetime, metronic

Using iPhone: - Issue (only for iPhone)

In the Date & Time of Appointment, after clicking the calendar icon then it will lag when changing Date/Time. Another phone (Android) should be no problem, only iPhone cannot work. I am using this template https://keenthemes.com/metronic/ to create my project and create datetime function.

Below is my coding:

`Datetime code`

```html
<Form.Group>
<Form.Label>
  <FormattedMessage id="GENERAL.DATE_TIME_APPOINTMENT" />
</Form.Label>
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
  <KeyboardDateTimePicker
    className="form-control"
    value={formatDateTimeStringAsDateTime(selectedDate)}
    onChange={handleDateChange}
    name="appointmentDate"
    minDate={new Date()}
    format={SAASDateTimeFormat}
    margin="dense"
  />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</Form.Group>
```

`MomentUtils`

```html
export default class MomentUtils implements IUtils<defaultMoment.Moment> {
    moment: typeof defaultMoment;
    locale?: string;
    yearFormat: string;
    yearMonthFormat: string;
    dateTime12hFormat: string;
    dateTime24hFormat: string;
    time12hFormat: string;
    time24hFormat: string;
    dateFormat: string;
    constructor({ locale, instance, moment }?: Opts);
    parse(value: string, format: string): defaultMoment.Moment;
    date(value?: any): defaultMoment.Moment;
    isValid(value: any): boolean;
    isNull(date: Moment): boolean;
    getDiff(date: Moment, comparing: Moment | string): number;
    isAfter(date: Moment, value: Moment): boolean;
    isBefore(date: Moment, value: Moment): boolean;
    isAfterDay(date: Moment, value: Moment): boolean;
    isBeforeDay(date: Moment, value: Moment): boolean;
    isBeforeYear(date: Moment, value: Moment): boolean;
    isAfterYear(date: Moment, value: Moment): boolean;
    startOfDay(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment;
    endOfDay(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment;
    format(date: Moment, formatString: string): string;
    formatNumber(numberToFormat: string): string;
    getHours(date: Moment): number;
    addDays(date: Moment, count: number): defaultMoment.Moment;
    setHours(date: Moment, count: number): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getMinutes(date: Moment): number;
    setMinutes(date: Moment, count: number): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getSeconds(date: Moment): number;
    setSeconds(date: Moment, count: number): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getMonth(date: Moment): number;
    isSameDay(date: Moment, comparing: Moment): boolean;
    isSameMonth(date: Moment, comparing: Moment): boolean;
    isSameYear(date: Moment, comparing: Moment): boolean;
    isSameHour(date: Moment, comparing: Moment): boolean;
    setMonth(date: Moment, count: number): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getMeridiemText(ampm: "am" | "pm"): "AM" | "PM";
    startOfMonth(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment;
    endOfMonth(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getNextMonth(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getPreviousMonth(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getMonthArray(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment[];
    getYear(date: Moment): number;
    setYear(date: Moment, year: number): defaultMoment.Moment;
    mergeDateAndTime(date: Moment, time: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment;
    getWeekdays(): string[];
    isEqual(value: any, comparing: any): boolean;
    getWeekArray(date: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment[][];
    getYearRange(start: Moment, end: Moment): defaultMoment.Moment[];
    getCalendarHeaderText(date: Moment): string;
    getYearText(date: Moment): string;
    getDatePickerHeaderText(date: Moment): string;
    getDateTimePickerHeaderText(date: Moment): string;
    getMonthText(date: Moment): string;
    getDayText(date: Moment): string;
    getHourText(date: Moment, ampm: boolean): string;
    getMinuteText(date: Moment): string;
    getSecondText(date: Moment): string;
}
```

`handleChange`

```html
const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedDate(e);
    setApptCheckingStartDate(e);
    setEndTime(e);
    setDurationHour("0");
    setDurationMinute("0");
  };
```

**selectedDate** value is fetching today's date.

This is my video to show how lagging in the select DateTime in the iPhone. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v4Aw7_ihS7M3Y40Rr3gY3OCHnqmR0rSG/view?usp=sharing

Anyone can help me on how to solve this problem so let the iPhone can be avoided the lagging issue for select DateTime? Thanks.